# atop not showing full command line with -c

Tags: shell, unix

I'm using atop to watch for a runaway process on a web server, but having some trouble getting it to show the full command line. With "atop -c" running, I run "/var/www/html/build test" a few times in another window, but atop just shows the following:

[image: atop output]

Importantly, the command line output is missing the arguments ("test"). It's clearly showing them for some commands, though (for example, the searchd call).

Any thoughts on why arguments aren't showing?